# PHP Facebook fql query returning empty array

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I just moved my code from my developer server to the live site and the Facebook api doesn't return the correct FQL results it should. In fact it returns an empty array. I've checked the permissions and those seem to be in order. The query in question does work on my dev server and also works in the explore graph tool.

The query in question:

```
$fql = "SELECT post_id, actor_id, created_time, updated_time, likes.count, attachment.media.video.source_url, attachment.name
            FROM stream WHERE source_id = ".$this->id." AND (attachment.caption = 'soundcloud.com' or attachment.caption = 'www.youtube.com')
            ORDER BY created_time DESC limit 30";
```

This query however does work using the php sdk:

```
$fql = "SELECT post_id, actor_id, created_time, updated_time, likes.count, attachment.media.video.source_url, attachment.name
            FROM stream WHERE source_id = ".$this->id." ORDER BY created_time DESC limit 30";
```

**Update**

If I run the query via a proxy server or in my own browser it also works. So the problem has to do something with the server. I tried Increasing the timeout, but this didn't do anything.

**Update**

I think I've encountered a know bug:
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/305190986273056

Any clues you can find?

Comment: You're missing a `"` at the end of your first and second query

Comment: Also, I would put the quoted sections of your query in `'` as opposed to `"` - for example, `'soundcloud.com'`

Comment: The missing " was a typo in my post. The single quotes don't seem to make a difference

Comment: get rid of `AND (attachment.caption = \"soundcloud.com\" or attachment.caption = \"www.youtube.com\")` all together and see if it works. I have a feeling this is the source of the error. Once you do that, see what the values of source_id are (add it to your select statement) - it's possible that the query just is not finding these values maybe?

Comment: Yes, it's works without it. It mention it in my post, the second query. It's weird, because the query did work on my other server and it works in the explorer tool.